# How to convert BigDecimal to Double in Java?

Tags: java

How we convert `BigDecimal` into `Double` in java? I have a requirement where we have to use Double as argument but we are getting `BigDecimal` so i have to convert `BigDecimal` into `Double`.

Comment: How about `new BigDecimal(2).doubleValue()`

Comment: Always Read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) before asking a question. You will often find that your question is answered. See [`doubleValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#doubleValue()). (Hint: to find the documentation for a specific class, simply google search the class name, followed by java. For example, to find this documentation, I searched "BigDecimal Java")

Comment: "I have a requirement where we have to use Double as argument" Get the requirement changed. There's no point in using `BigDecimal` at all unless you use it end-to-end. This requirement compromises accuracy; may compromise regulatory compliance; and may constitute actionable negligence.

Comment: Why are you using `Double` and not `double`. Is it a field which can be `null`?

Comment: @EJP Using `double` is not that bad, but as it has 15+ digits of representation accuracy which is more than most programs need, but I agree there is no point using BigDecimal some of the time as you are more likely to add bugs/complexity.

Comment: @PeterLawrey If he has a requirement to use `BigDecimal,` he has an implicit or explicit collateral requirement not to use double for the same data.

Comment: @EJP I agree, If you are using BigDecimal, there should be a good reason for it.

Answer (score 319, accepted):

You need to use the [`doubleValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#doubleValue()) method to get the double value from a BigDecimal object.

```
BigDecimal bd; // the value you get/receive from your source

// In case there is a chance that the incoming BigDecimal value is  null,
// please add an appropriate null check before you invoke the doubleValue() method on that object.
double d = bd.doubleValue(); // The "double" you want
```

Comment: Hi, i used same, But the problem is both anser are different my decimal output was 13555261857.79 and when converted to double its 1.355526185779E10 .. How do i get same output after converting decimal to double

Comment: @user13926345 - Both are the same values. Just that the first output is the normal representation of the value and the other is the [scientific representation](https://chortle.ccsu.edu/java5/Notes/chap11/ch11_5.html).

Comment: hi, it worked for me... straightforward solution

Comment: But this wont work if we want to keep it possible to have null values. Do you have a solution that can fix that?

Comment: @dagrun - I've updated the answer to clarify that the user needs to add appropriate null checks in case the incoming value can be null. The intent of the answer was and still is, to guide the user towards the right source to achieve their primary goal of transforming a BigDecimal to double and not provide a piece of code (with all possible `if` conditions) without knowing what conditions may apply to their requirements. I hope that helps clarify your doubt.

Answer (score 40):

You can convert `BigDecimal` to `double` using [`.doubleValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#doubleValue%28%29). But believe me, don't use it if you have currency manipulations. It should always be performed on `BigDecimal` objects directly. Precision loss in these calculations are big time problems in currency related calculations.

Comment: Can you please describe the problem with example ?

Answer (score 13):

Use [doubleValue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#doubleValue%28%29) method present in [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class :

```
double doubleValue()
```

Converts this `BigDecimal` to a `double`.